# PIP --upgrade not working on Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I do have Python version 3.8.2 and an outdated version of PIP. I am using a Mac, and when I try to upgrade PIP by doing `pip install --upgrade pip` I'm getting this error message:

````
➜  ~ pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==18.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
➜  ~ ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reinstall pip manually by following the steps [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) described.

1. Donwload [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Run `python get-pip.py` in the folder you downloaded the python script to.
3. Then, you can use pip normally.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` runs the 2.7 pip.  Look at the traceback.  `pip3` runs a 3.x pip, and if 3.8 is the only one, 3.8.  `python3 -m pip` will run some 3.x pip and `python3.8 -m pip` will only run 3.8 pip.  I recommend that you first upgrade to 3.8.7.  I forget whether the python.org installer has an option to upgrade pip with it.  If not,

```
python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

should work (I just ran it).  If not

```
python3.8 -m ensurepip
```

should install a recent pip which can be upgraded.